# Vertical align a marginpar with the *first* line of a 2-line statement

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginpar

I have an article in which I'd like to use margin notes near some text (some minor headings, equivalent with a subsubsubsection).

In some cases that text runs on two lines. I'd like the margin note to be vertically align with the first line of those two, not the second (as it happens now as seen in the screenshot).

[image]

Is it possible? Many thanks in advance.

```
\usepackage{mparhack}
\reversemarginpar

% <snip>
\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.} 
\marginpar{\sc{\small{Case~1}}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wouldn't moving the `\marginpar` to the front of your text work for you? E.g., `\newcommand{\mysubsubsub}[2]{\textbf{\marginpar{\sc{\small{#1}}}#2}}`.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it helps to place the `marginpar` content near the beginning of the considered paragraph.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mparhack}

\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}
  \textbf{Lorem\marginpar{\textmd{\textsc{\small Case 1}}} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.} 
\end{document}
```