# How do I align a marginal note with the first line of the paragraph immediately following it?

Tags: margins, marginpar, marginnote

I would like margin notes in the left margin, aligned with the first line of a paragraph, similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5132/vertical-align-a-marginpar-with-the-first-line-of-a-2-line-statement). Basically these are headings for the paragraph. In the source code, I'd like the margin note to *precede* the paragraph it's meant to be attached to, for readability (the reader will read the margin note first, so I want to write it first).

The linked question says that this should work, but for me this aligns the margin note with the last line of the *previous* paragraph:

```
\marginpar{Note}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Comment: `\leavevmode\marginpar{...}` will do if there is no blank line (`\par`) between it and the next paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

This allows a blank line between `\nextmarginpar` and the next paragraph.

I experimented with `\everypar`, but it also runs too soon.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\newcommand{\nextmarginpar}[2][\empty]{% same as \marginpar
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \leavevmode\marginpar{#2}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}\par
  \else
    \leavevmode\marginpar[#1]{#2}\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}\par
  \fi
  \ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\nextmarginpar{Note}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\marginpar` is not the right tool for the job. If this is a section header, it should be done with `\section` with the formatting to put the header in the margin. The following is some undocumented code I wrote that does this at the `\subsection` level.

```
\def\subsection{\@afterindentfalse\secdef\@subsection\@ssubsection}

\def\@subsection[#1]#2{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth>1
     \refstepcounter{subsection}
     \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}%
  \else
     \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}%
  \fi
  \subsectionmark{#1}
  \vskip 12pt plus2pt minus1pt
  \def\@svsechd{\raggedright\reset@font\normalsize\textit{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>1\relax\thesubsection~\fi#2}}
        \@@afterheading}

\def\@ssubsection#1{\def\@svsechd{\reset@font\raggedleft\large\sc#1}%
   \@@afterheading}

\def\@@afterheading{\global\@nobreaktrue    
      \everypar{\if@nobreak
                   \global\@nobreakfalse
                   \if@afterindent \else {\setbox0=\lastbox}\fi
%                   \interlinepenalty \@M                   
                   \vadjust{\llap{\vbox to0pt{\vskip-9pt
                     \vtop{\hsize\marginparwidth
                       \@svsechd}\vss}\hskip\marginparsep}}%
                   \clubpenalty \@M
                 \else \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
                   \interlinepenalty \@interlinepenalty
                    \everypar{}\fi}}
```

There is a limitation with this code that if there is a `\subsubsection` immediately following the `\subsection` that the header will disappear.¹

This code is a bit old and I likely would have done somethings differently if I were creating it from scratch now, but it should be at least a good starting point.

---

1. “Doctor, it hurts when I do this.”

   “Then don’t do that.”